# Error reporting knowing where it is in the code

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a stream called "err" which is in the namespace Errors. This is how the developer is meant to report errors in a user friendly way. So when something goes wrong the dev will write the error message as such:

```
Errors::err << "Oh no. That was a bad thing.";
```

Is it possible to use the preprocessor to append `[__FILE__:__LINE__]` to the error message without changing the current error reporting style? I.e. the above command would now (after preprocessing magic) output this to an error file:

> Oh no. That was a bad thing. [file.cc:20]

I have tried this myself, but the **C** Preprocessor doesn't seem to like namespaces, and I don't feel I can go replacing "err" everywhere in the code - which would be an even bigger issue if a dev decides to use `using Errors::err` or `using namespace Errors`.

In the scope of what I want to achieve, is the C-Preprocessor fundamentally incompatible with the coding style? If so are there any other methods (perhaps Makefile based?) to do what I wish?

Comment: The preprocessor has no knowledge of namespaces. It is a simple text replacement tool that occurs before your code is even really parsed.

Comment: I think this can be done, but it might be a bit odd.  Working on it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible with your current style. The routines called at runtime don't know who calls them. You can, however, [obtain the backtrace using platform-specific functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Backtraces.html) and write that.

If you could replace all error reporting code eg. with

```
REPORT_ERROR( "Oh no. That was a bad thing." );
```

it would be easy. You'd just `#define` the macro

```
#define REPORT_ERROR(x) Errors::err << x << "[" << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "]" << endl;
```

Comment: So in essence, to keep the current coding style AND achieve what I want I'd have to use some sort of more advanced preprocessor? I.e. one that does more than simple substitutions? Does m4/autotools have the capability?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I can only think of bizarre solutions that either pollute the namespace or involve use of some automatic code patcher (like coccinelle, which, however, works only for C AFAIK).

Comment: This is the standard solution to this problem, but I think there might be a way to do what OP wants...

Comment: @John Dibling: Yes. Your solution is exactly what I called "bizarre solution that pollute the namespace". Imagine what happens when there's an `int` in some function called `err`...

Comment: @jpaleck:  If there is a free function called `err`, I'd say the namespace is already pretty well polluted.  Anyway, you can give my macro a different, better name.

Comment: @jpalecek: I have found prefixing easier to use than function-macros, ie have `#define REPORT_ERROR()` build a temporary and then stream into it avoid bizarre macros bugs with what is passed in.

Comment: @John Dibling: He uses a separate namespace, `Errors::err`, so he can freely use variables named `err`, free and member functions called `err`, classes called `err`. This is not namespace pollution, this is exactly what all the namespaces, scoping and such are for. Also, if he ever used a using-declaration `using Errors::err`, your solution would break it. Giving the macro a better name sort of defeats the purpose, since the OP doesn't want to edit any code...

Comment: @jpalecek:  I'm not sure I see how my solution pollutes the namespace, then.  He did have something in `Errors` names `err` -- but I replaced it.  That was, as you indirectly point out, the whole idea.  My solution certainly is funky, I don't dispute that.  But there's really nowhere else to go (which I can see) that doesn't involve re-writing all the code that user `Errors::err`.

Comment: @John Dibling: The point about polluting the namespace is that your `#define` not only replaces `err` variable in `Errors`, but also clobbers completely unrelated `err` variables in `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` (such as `int err=read(fd, buffer, length)`. "But there's really nowhere else to go that doesn't involve re-writing all the code that user Errors::err." - exactly. And the sane way is to rewrite the code.

Comment: @John Dibling: Another really good solution would be using a tool that's designed for such work, such as AspectC++.

Comment: After a little consideration I've come to the conclusion that I'm doing it wrong. My error streams are a good framework to build upon, but automatically adding `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` info isn't always necessary. In fact, the use case that I have it probably isn't necessary at all - there's other, more useful (probably) information that I can put in. The key thing I'm taking from this is to choose what is useful for your error messages, rather than doing the same for everything.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, I think this works.  You should note that doing this might be a bad idea, because this code is funky at best, downright faulty or invalid at worst.  I haven't really tested or examined this deeply, but I know that it compiles and runs on my system (Windows 7/MSVC10).  If I saw something like this in production code, I'd probably consider it a hack and would have to be convinced otherwise.

Enjoy.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Errors
{
    class errstream
    {
    public:
        errstream(const std::string& filename, int lineno) : file_(filename), line_(lineno) {};
        std::string dump() const;
        errstream& operator<<(const std::string& msg)
        {
            cout << msg << "\t[" << file_ << ":" << line_ << "]";
            return * this;
        }
    private:
        std::string file_;
        int line_;
    };
};

 #define err errstream(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    Errors::err << "Oh no. That was a bad thing.";
}
```

The output is (for me):

> Oh no. That was a bad thing.    [main.cpp:30]

### EDIT: ROUND 2

In the comments below, a new requirement was stated.  The OP wanted to be able to do something like this:

```
Errors::err << "File Not Found '" << file << "'  What A Bummer. :(";
```

...and have the output be:

> File not found! 'foo.txt' What a bummer. :(     [file:nnn]

My original code will not produce this output because it cannot handle multiple stream insertions with just a single appended token for the location.  The output instead becomes a big mess:

> File not found! '       [main.cpp:61]foo.txt    [main.cpp:61]' What a
>   bummer. :(        [main.cpp:61 ]

This can be accomodated by having `errstream` dump its contents to `cout` when the destructor is called, rather than when the stream insertion operator is called.  The stream insertion operator, in turn, somply collects the tokens that will be dumped to cout before the location string.  New code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

namespace Errors
{
    class errstream
    {
    public:
        errstream(const std::string& filename, int lineno) : file_(filename), line_(lineno) {};
        ~errstream()
        {
            std::copy(tokens_.begin(), tokens_.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout));
            cout << "\t[" << file_ << ":" << line_ << "]\n";
        }
        errstream& operator<<(const std::string& msg)
        {
            tokens_.push_back(msg);
            return *this;
        }
    private:
        typedef std::vector<std::string> Tokens;
        Tokens tokens_;
        std::string file_;
        int line_;
    };
};

 #define err errstream(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    Errors::err << "Oh no. That was a bad thing.";

    string file = "foo.txt";
    Errors::err << "File not found! '" << file << "' What a bummer. :(";

}
```

The output is now:

> Oh no. That was a bad thing.    [main.cpp:38]
>
> File not found! 'foo.txt' What a bummer. :(     [main.cpp:41]

Comment: Looking at this, it has a few disadvantages? For example you can't do "stacked" streaming, beacuse that'll put [main.cpp:30] after every string, which you will do if you put specific information into an error (like which picture failed or something). However this could be combatted by PREPENDING the info by putting it into the constructor.
Also, is replacing "err" a safe thing to do? I guess I don't know the Preprocessor well enough because I'm surprised it doesn't replace the "err" in "errstream". Plus wouldn't error messages with the word "error" in them fail?

Comment: Re the preprocessor not substituting `err` in `errstream` -- it only replaces whole tokens.

Comment: Re disadvantages.  Sure, this was just a quick hack designed to accomplish specifically what you asked for.  If you want to be able to do this: `Errors::err << "File not found! '" << file_ << "'  What a bummer!";`  ...then I think we can reingineer this to accommodate that.  Gimme a few minutes.

Comment: As there's no assignment of the stream, when is the destructor called? When the scope closes? Or immediately? (I'd normally assume it's the end of scope).
If your error causes a seg-fault, the error report will never get sent in the first case.

Comment: In the use case you posited, you are creating a temporary: `Errors::err << ...;`  The temporary object is guaranteed to be destroyed at the end of the sequence point -- in other words, at the `;`.

Comment: Now you want fault tolerance?  LOL, the requirements just keep on comin'!  In all seriousness, fault tolerance can be applied to this class just like with any other.  Since that is beyond the scope of this post, I'll leave that as an excercise for the reader. :)